# UITextView can not detect link & address in iOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I have iOS application which supports iOS 6 as well as iOS 7. Now I am showing text in UITextView which contains email address & website urls. In iOS 6 , UITextView detects it correctly but in iOS 7 it doesn't detect when view gets loaded. But when I click on any link , email address it starts detecting all the link / urls.

Is this a bug in iOS 7 or I am missing some settings specially for iOS 7 ? Below are the screenshots of app

1) In iOS 6+ when view loaded

[image]

2) In iOS 7 when view loaded

[image]

3) In iOS 7 when I tap on any link / email address

[image]

4) Here is the settings that I am doing in Interface builder for UITextView.

[image]

I checked some links which states that , set

```
textView.text = nil;
textView.text = @"My required info";
```

But no luck with above code.

Can any body tell me whats going wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 7.0's UITextViews. You should check out NSDataDetector.You can use this to find links, phone numbers and more  http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/

It appears that the trick is to `textView.scrollEnabled = NO`. Seems to fix the problem, although if you need scrolling.

Answer (score 9):

It appears that on 7.1 links are detected when `Selectable` but not `Editable`.

(IB reports Unsupported Configuration: Data Detection and Editable attributes are mutually exclusive)

Answer (score 1):

try just to retype "xyz@gmail.com" or different address.
I had the same issues and had to retype email addresses instead of copy/pasting them.