# UITextView Not Detecting Links

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` whose content I have set in my .xib.

I am trying to get it to recognize a link using these settings:

[image: Settings]

Unfortunately the link does not show up when I run in the simulator (it only shows as plain text):

[image: In simulator]

How can I get the `UITextView` to recognize the link and display it properly?

Comment: How about adding http:// prefix to the link text?

Comment: @sha Thanks for the suggestion but still the same.

Comment: Is it iOS7? There are seems to be a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488143/uitextview-can-not-detect-link-address-in-ios-7

Comment: @sha I am on iOS 7. I tried `self.creditsTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;` as suggested and still nothing. I hope they fix this soon.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set your Textview behavior to Selectable ,

[image]

And make sure you have enabled User Interaction .

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why does the selectable make the difference?

Comment: How can I make it not selectable and make link detection work? By not selectable I mean unable to select a piece of the text to copy

Comment: I realize this is old, but selectable is required because the links you want the textView to manifest would be user selectable. If they can't select the text, they can't select the link.

Comment: Make sure UITextview is not editable. Its wont work if its editable

Comment: How does WhatsApp achieve this? Their only links are selectable and rest of the text is not. Could someone tell how that could be done?